# Display result variable by Key(Values) C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

My result in the MessageBox is `lTest` concatenated by strings.  If I have dupilicate Keys, how can I group them by Key(Values)?  For instance if Monday appears four times and Tuesday once, instead of Monday, Monday, Monday, Monday, Tuesday. I want it to appear Monday(4), Tuesday(1).

```
List<int> lNetworkIds = new List<int>();
Dictionary<DisplayDay, int> numDayOccurances = new Dictionary<DisplayDay, int>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// get a list of distinct network id's for this proposal
foreach (Proposal lDetail in this._Proposal.Details)
{
    if (!lNetworkIds.Contains(lDetail.NetworkId))
        lNetworkIds.Add(lDetail.NetworkId);
    if (!numDayOccurances.ContainsKey(lDetail.Daypart))
        numDayOccurances[lDetail.Daypart] = 0;
    numDayOccurances[lDetail.Daypart]++;
}

if (numDayOccurances.Count > 0)
{

    string lTest = String.Join(", ", numDayOccurances.Keys);

    MessageBox.Show(lTest);

}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `DisplayDay`? you surely have to group by key.

Comment: What exactly are these keys?

Comment: So what problem are you having with your code; it looks fine to me.  Are you getting an error, are the results not what you expect, or what?

Comment: DisplayDay is a class

Comment: Well what does the class look like?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
MessageBox.Show(
string.Join(",", 
numDayOccurances.Keys.GroupBy(r=> r.DayOfWeek)
                .Select(grp => string.Format("{0}({1})", grp.Key, grp.Count())));
```

Considering your class `DisplayDay` looks like:

```
class DisplayDay
{
    public string  DayOfWeek { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if i was not more specific. The class returns more then days of week. I used that as an example. As of now the result lTest returns exactly what i need. I was looking for a loop that loops through lTest and depending on how many times the key occurs then group as Monday(5) if it occurs 5 times.

Comment: "how many times the key occurs" , what do you mean ?? you can't have duplicate keys in `Dictionary`

Comment: Sorry a little new to this. In my code the result of lTest shows at Monday, Monday, Monday, Tuesday. It will always return as different results depending on what the client chooses. I just want to loop through those results and check in Monday exists 5 times then instead of displaying it 5 times just display Monday(5)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear from your question what you want to do, but if you have a list of days like so:

```
var days = new List<DayOfWeek> { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Monday,   DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday };

var result = from d in days
group d by d into g
select new
{
    g.Key,
    Count = g.Count()
};
```

Results in:

```
Key       Count
Monday    3 
Tuesday   1 
Wednesday 1
```

You can then write this to a string as you see fit, for example:

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.Select(a => String.Format("{0} ({1})", a.Key, a.Count)))
```

Gives:

> Monday (3)
>   Tuesday (1)
>   Wednesday (1)